# Different widgets one configuration activity android

Tags: android, configuration, layout, android-activity, android-widget

Some apps clog up the select widget activity by adding different configuration activities. like the screenshot here: [Multi Configuration activities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBKvP.png)

Is there a way to have one icon in the select widget (like Mini Info) and one configuration activity and set different layouts for widgets there?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Some apps clog up the select widget activity by adding different configuration activities.

Those are not multiple configuration activities. Those are multiple metadata files, to provide multiple sizes of the app widget.

> Is there a way to have one icon in the
>   select widget (like Mini Info) and one
>   configuration activity and set
>   different layouts for widgets there?

Layouts? Yes. Size? No. The size is part of the metadata file and cannot be modified at runtime.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. Would I have to define multiple metadata files then use the configuration activity to select one? Can you give me a small example of how this should be done?

Comment: @zsniper: "Would I have to define multiple metadata files then use the configuration activity to select one?" -- no, you would have multiple `<receiver>` entries in your manifest, each with a distinct label and each pointing to the appropriate metadata file. "Can you give me a small example of how this should be done?" -- no, sorry.